# Selecting a Datalist element tied to input by using enter key

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

With a simple input and datalist combination like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control dropdown-input" id="standardInput" name="standardInput" tabindex="7" list="listForStandardInput"/>
<datalist id="listForStandardInput"></datalist>
```

I would like to enable keyboard navigation and selection. When focus is inside the input element I can use the up/down arrow keys to make selections but when I hit the enter key a form submission occurs.

When I use jQuery-based JavaScript to try and prevent that the form still submits.

```
$(function () {
    'use strict';
    $('#standardInput').on('keypress', function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }); 
});
```

Is there anyway I can allow the use of the enter key to select elements of the datalist that is tied to the input element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `keyup()` instead:

```
$("#standardInput").keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();            
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried this as well but no dice. I even tried applying the keydown event but when I hit enter on the field the form still submits.

Comment: I had an additional event handler on the page; after removing the conflicting event handler this code worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try using e.which instead of e.keyCode.

```
$(function () {
    'use strict';
    $('#standardInput').on('keypress', function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }); 
});
```